# Masking no longer working in adobe animate for me

Tags: mask, adobe-animate

I've used the 'mask' effect a few times. But suddenly it no longer works. Even if I create a brand new scene, and just draw something on a layer, using 'b'. Create a new layer, draw a circle, with 'b', then fill it with 'k', when I set this second layer to mask the first, nothing happens.

Weirdly, if I 'Preview' the scene, the mask is working ok...

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that my mask and everything was all correct. "All" I needed to do was select "close" from the file menu, then re-open the same animation file, and then the mask worked fine....